# Raycast Not Detecting idle object in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d platformer game in unity. I'm trying to create an enemy moves forward and turn when he meets a wall or on the edge of the platform so I gave him this prototype script

```
public float speed;
public float raylength;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private int dir = -1;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * dir, rb.velocity.y);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2(dir, 0), raylength);
    if(hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.name!="Slime")
        print(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag=="Ground")
    {
        dir*=-1;
    }
}
```

for some reason the slime only prints player when the player is moving and only prints ground when he enters the ground after few seconds I tried setting his speed to 0 and making the player collide with it but it only print player when he collides with the origin of the raycast  althought i tried to set the ray length to insane numbers but same result.
if you are interested in the values of the rigidbody and the box collider so i activated is trigger in the box collider and made him kinematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raycast will detect only one object, I think yours is detecting the object from where ray is originating. Go to Edit>Project settings>Physics2d> Uncheck Queries start in Colliders.

Now your Raycast should detect objects outside your parent object.